# PHP _GET issue not refreshing data on multiple tries

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, html

I have a php script that is triggered from my app. This script uses the GET method to retrieve information from the url and put it into a database. I have got it to work so far except for the fact when I try to do multiple requests.

For example, I did a test where every time I would take the name of the database from the GET, put it into the appropriate database, retrieve the last entry, and then it would add 7 each time and echo it to the screen/put it back into the database as the newest number. I tried this within my browser hitting refresh every time and the first time it worked. Second time I hit refresh, it gave me the same results as the first time. I kept trying but same result so I closed the browser and tried it again. It worked as it should.

So the problem I think has to do with the script not receiving the connection the second, third, fourth... time around. It seems to only work the first time. I thought this was an issue with the data being cached but I turned off cache within the php script.

Can someone please tell me why it only works on the first attempt?

Thanks

**EDITED WITH CODE**

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

checkToken();

function checkToken ()
{



$username='XXXXX';
$password='XXXXX';
$database='Push';


$passed= $_GET['token'];


$pieces = explode(" ", $passed); /*Contains two pieces of information.  
                                       First is for the correct table and 
                                       and the second is the actually data 
                                       that will be put into the tables*/
$search= $pieces[1];

$table= $pieces[0];

echo $table." ".$search;

 $db= new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Error: Could not connect';
    exit;

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Tokens` WHERE `Number` LIKE '%$search%' ";


       echo "after";

$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result) {
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


    echo $row;

    if (!$row)
    {
        echo "No Token, insert into database";
        insertToken($table,$pieces[1]);

        return;

    }

   /*problem may be around here...? does not always go into (!row)
     after the first time when it is supposed too*/

echo $row['Numbers'];


} else {
   // echo "Query failed: {$db->error}\n";

    echo "No";

}

}




function insertToken ($daTable, $daToken)
{

$username='XXXX';
$password='XXXX';
$database='Push';

 $token=$daToken;

 $con= mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);

  mysql_select_db($database,$con);

  $res = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO $daTable
VALUES ('', '$token')");
if (!$res) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 } else  {
echo "complete";
 }

mysql_close($link);

  }
```

Comment: no matter how well you think you're describing your problem...post some code ;-)

Comment: If you keep hitting refresh, the same URL is sent... so why would you get different results??

Comment: @YaronUliel  See edited answer... Thanks. Please note that the code given is the script that my app sends data too. Within the data sent is two pieces of code (hence the explode with the _GET). First piece is the correct table to insert the code into and the second piece is the string to be put in

Comment: @Pr0no See edited answer... Thanks. Please note that the code given is the script that my app sends data too. Within the data sent is two pieces of code (hence the explode with the _GET). First piece is the correct table to insert the code into and the second piece is the string to be put in

Comment: @Hamish No for my test script I wrote with the same functions pretty much, it always stored the number that 7 was added too. So the next time the last entry in the row would have another 7 added on and etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a cache problem? try to make sure the code gets executed at all, like echoing the time

Comment: Possibly... See edited answer for what I did to turn of the cache problem within the script. Thanks

Comment: well what I read is: if row corresponding to token doesn't exist, insert it. if it does, do nothing. why would you expect an action here after the first hit?

Comment: "an action" meaning, in particular, branching into !row

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It calls another method insertToken which if it doesn't exist puts it into the database. Correct?

Comment: yea. but how is the database supposed to change at the second call? if you call it again, it finds nothing to insert, and sets the field to the same value it's already set to. so "no effect" seems to be the desired behaviour, but you don't seem happy with it either. think I'm missing something